# Error in read context.read(incrementProvider).increment();

Tags: flutter

Error in read context.read(incrementProvider).increment();
Can someone help me? i tried ref.read but its turn red

Error in read context.read(incrementProvider).increment();
Can someone help me? i tried ref.read but its turn red

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class IncrementNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _value = 0;
  int get value => _value;
  void increment() {
    _value++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final incrementProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => IncrementNotifier());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Riverpod Tutorial',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Riverpod Tutorial'),
        ),
        body: Center(
         child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, ref, child) {
              final incrementNotifier = ref.watch(incrementProvider);
              return Text(incrementNotifier.value.toString());
            },
            
          ),
          
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            context.read(incrementProvider).increment();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version use are using?

Comment: flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3 this version

Answer (score 1):

In `flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3`, you have to use `ref` instead of `context`.

Try to wrap your `floatingActionButton` with `Consumer` and then use `ref` to `read` the `provider`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Riverpod Tutorial',
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Riverpod Tutorial'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context, ref, child) {
                  final incrementNotifier = ref.watch(incrementProvider);
                  return Text(incrementNotifier.value.toString());
                },
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: Consumer(
              builder: (context, ref, child) {
                return FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(incrementProvider).increment();
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```